# Design pattern of `onAction` for a button on a ribbon

Tags: c#, event-handling, ribbon

My ribbon has a few buttons (at the moment it's only a split button and a couple of buttons on the menu belonging thereto) on my ribbon. Hence, I have a choice of two different design patterns for the action handlers.

Pattern #1 (common method)

```
<button id="Beep" onAction="DoStuff" />
<button id="Boop" onAction="DoStuff" />

public void DoStuff(Office.IRibbonControl control)
{
  if (control.Id == "Beep") { ... }
  if (control.Id == "Boop") { ... }
}
```

Pattern #2 (separate methods)

```
<button id="Beep" onAction="DoBeep" />
<button id="Boop" onAction="DoBoop" />

public void DoBeep(Office.IRibbonControl control) { ... }
public void DoBoop(Office.IRibbonControl control) { ... }
```

I'd go with pattern #2 (unless dealing with very small calls or really schematizable actions) **but** it seems to me that many articles advocate pattern #1 (which brings my thoughts to the Java actions listener patter à la 90's). Being new to ribbon reals, I'd still prefer to know what other programmers would suggest on the subject.

Comment: I'd go with #2, because that's the usual way you do stuff in other contexts (in my experience, Silverlight).  As I have no experience with ribbons or the standards that go with them, this is a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: @TimS. I corrected a typo. The commonly suggested approach I perceived to be pattern #1 (a single, common method), which is why I got unsure as to the standards (or at the very least recommendations). As you, I also believe that pattern #2 is the most correct way to go. As you, I have no prior experience with ribbon but it feels good to see that others (**other**, perhaps, since you've posted the only reply so far) also reason the way I do.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what your controls should do when your fire the event. If the controls have to execute something similar or you can generalize their actions then it's better to go with pattern 1, but in general it's better to use pattern 2, because your code will be easier to understand and your events will work well even if you change the value of those IDs.